# how to retrieve user data from FireStore in android

Tags: java, android

I want after the user sign is complete to get the status of that user and base on that status show him his activity if he is a admin then show him the admin activity if he is a ordinary user the show him the user activity.

```
    private void LoginUser(String email,String password){
        fAuth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email,password).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
            @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT)
            @Override
            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                if(task.isSuccessful()){
                    final DocumentReference documentReference = fStore.collection("users").document(fAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid());
                    documentReference.addSnapshotListener(new EventListener<DocumentSnapshot>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onEvent(@Nullable DocumentSnapshot documentSnapshot, @Nullable FirebaseFirestoreException e) {

                                 if(documentSnapshot.getString("Status").equals("user")){

                                     Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, "Login Successfully", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
//   startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(),HomeActivity.class));
                                     Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), HomeActivity.class);
                                     startActivity(intent);
                                     intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
                                     startActivity(intent);
                                 }else if(documentSnapshot.getString("Status").equals("Admin")){

                                     //Then move to the AdminActivity
                                     Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, "he is a Admin", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                 }else{
                                     //throw error
                                 }

                        }
                    });


                }else{
                    Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, "Error "+ Objects.requireNonNull(task.getException()).getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
                loadingBar.dismiss();
            }
        });
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend creating a Class, which represents the values coming back from your database, I am not sure of your naming convention or structure in your Firebase DB, so here is an example.

Kotlin:

```
class User {
    val name: String? = null
    val status: String? = null
}
```

Java:

```
public class User {

    private String name;
    private String status;

    public String getName() {
        if (name == null) {
            return "";
        }
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getStatus() {
        if (status == null) {
            return "";
        }
        return status;
    }

    public void setStatus(String status) {
        this.status = status;
    }
}
```

Then inside `onEvent` you should be able to do:

Kotlin:

```
val documentModel = documentSnapshot.document.toObject(User::class.java))

if(documentModel.status == "user"{
 //do your work
}
```

Java:

```
User documentModel = documentSnapshot.getDocument().toObject(User.class);
```

You might not need to do `.getDocument`, you might be able to just do `documentSnapshot.toObject` but as I am not near my IDE, I am having to guess.

I would also recommend making sure your snapshot is not empty before doing the above, so that you can handle accordingly.

Something like:

```
if (!documentSnapshots.isEmpty()) {
  // blah blah
}
```

PS; Your question isn't very clear, I am unsure if you're fetching your values ok, but your having issues with handling inside `onEvent` or if the whole method isn't working as expected and you're currently not retrieving any values. Regardless, I hope the above points you in the right direction.